# Подгрузка элементов при скроллинге

Tags: javascript, html

Собственно, есть страница, с 4 блоками, общей высотой где-то 2500px. И я бы хотел сделать появление каждого последующего блока при скроллинге страницы. Находил уйму кода с ajax-запросами и php, но хотел бы узнать способ попроще. Ведь контента немного, да и базы данных нет. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: а как вы без ajax собрались данные подгружать? без php откуда вы их брать будете? вы конечно можете весь добавляемый код запилить прям в JS и при прокрутке делать .append()...

Comment: Не знаю, честно говоря. В этом вопросе почти 0, думал, что для простых ситуаций есть простые решения

Comment: Ну можно изначально добавить весь контент, но последние три блока скрыть. При скролинге отображать. Появление будет, запросов к серверу нет.

Comment: А можно по-подробней об этом? Это был-бы хороший вариант в моем случае

Comment: Но тогда какой смысл их скрывать?

Comment: Уже решил отказаться от этой идеи. И вправду, для такого мелкого проекта излишне.